# How to Create a Multi-Column Custom Content Element

Tags: typo3, neoscms

I'm trying to create a custom two-column content element in Typo3 Neos. I'm aware that Neos is shipped with multi-column functionality, but for this particular case I need to create my own custom content element.

So far I've been able to create one of the columns (see below gist for code). However, as soon as I try to add the second column, the page just turns blank and no further changes can be made.

**Gists**

- 1 column activated (working properly): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5f33c7923faae26aa1a
- 2 columns activated (not working): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/85fc6994e9e2c5892a11

Any idea why that is happening, or how to solve this / build a multi-column custom content element in Neos?

Comment: Could you give some more details about the error? Either the Neos logs or the php logs should give you a hint on what is wrong. I guess a YAML formatting problem, but I cannot see it in your gist (which looks fine).

Comment: @ChristianM I took a look at the log files and it seems to be a problem with resolving the node of the second column.

On the following link you can find both the excerpt from the system.log of Neos as well as the referenced exception: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5390832d7e22b47bec88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I simply had to execute the following flow command to create the missing node:
./flow node:autocreatechildnodes --node-type Daniel.MultiColumn:TwoCol